# wine left to ferment

Tags: fermentation

I have been given some more wine stuff to add to my collection. In the goodies there are 2 fermenting bottles with wine in it.(strawberry wine) they have been in the bottles just over 4 years . I was told if I filter it it will be ok to drink. Is that ok or shall I play it safe and poor it away.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The wine will not start being poisonous after years of being in the bottle. If it is wood alcohol, it could, but if you know where it comes from, there is no harm in tasting it. If it does taste bad, pour it away and call it a day, if it tastes good, enjoy your fruit wine!

TL;DR; It should be safe to drink.